# Firebase: How can I ensure compatibility with various versions of Google Play Services?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to incorporate messaging/Push notifications in my Android App and since FCM is the newest version recommended, I just checked the Firebase prerequisites and it says,

> **Prerequisites**
>
> - A device running Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) or newer, and    Google Play services 10.2.0 or higher
> - The Google Play services SDK from the Google Repository, available in    the Android SDK Manager
> - The latest version of Android Studio, version 1.5 or higher

But, it isn't so that all the devices running ICS will have Google Play Services >= 10.2.0. Infact, this is the latest version of it. So, if I decide to go with FCM, all the devices having Play Services <= 10.2.0 will be out of my reach. If then I decide to bump the version down, Firebase doesn't seem to support any.

I want to use Firebase's and Google Play Services newest features and extend my support for devices running Google Play services >= 9.0.0.

This seems to be a fundamental problem with any library. Android provides Support library to mitigate this.

What is the recommended approach to support all these Play Services versions?

Comment: the requirements that you listed are true for most of the Firebase libraries, but for FCM any version of Google Play services is sufficient. The answer provided by AL. is still relevant, because most likely you want to have other correctly working Firebase services (like Analytics). But for FCM only any version of Google Play services is ok, as long as some version of GPs is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have the user update to the latest Google Play Services, by placing *checkers*. From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-play):

> Apps that rely on the Play Services SDK should always check the device for a compatible Google Play services APK before accessing Google Play services features. It is recommended to do this in two places: in the main activity's `onCreate()` method, and in its `onResume()` method. The check in `onCreate()` ensures that the app can't be used without a successful check. The check in `onResume()` ensures that if the user returns to the running app through some other means, such as through the back button, the check is still performed.
>
> If the device doesn't have a compatible version of Google Play services, your app can call [GoogleApiAvailability.makeGooglePlayServicesAvailable()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability.html#public-methods) to allow users to download Google Play services from the Play Store.

Answer (score 1):

Every device API 14 or higher (the [new minimum SDK version as of 10.2.0](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/google-play-services-and-firebase-for-android-will-support-api-level-14-at-minimum.html)) that has Google Play services is automatically upgraded to the latest version of Google Play services - in fact, a new version of the API only becomes available to developers when it is available on 100% of devices.

Comment: This is not true. My device has API level 22 and Google Play Services 10.0.84. There is no update pending nor there is any prompt.

Comment: @pulp_fiction - Are you expecting Google Play services to show up in the Play Store or show as an 'Update available'? Because that's not how it works: Google Play services silently updates in the background and doesn't show up in the Play Store unless you specifically go to the listing (generally from the Google Settings, Help & Feedback, View in Play Store). Are you saying when you specifically go to the listing it does not show an update available? Or just that your device has not yet silently updated?

Comment: I updated my App to use GPS 10.2.0 and on installing the App, it auto prompted for updation of the services. So, the your silent updating theory is spot on. Thanks.