# Checking if Google Play Service is enabled for FCM

Tags: android, google-play-services, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it necessary to check if the Google Play Service is enabled if I want to use FCM ? My app has to support OS 4.0 and above. It is going to be distributed through Play Store only so I assume Google Play Service should be by default enabled on users' devices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase: How can I ensure compatibility with various versions of Google Play Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848522/firebase-how-can-i-ensure-compatibility-with-various-versions-of-google-play-se)

Answer (score 2):

There are different states of Play Services. You can check for `ConnectionResult.SUCCESS`. To be exact you can check state of GPS using

```
     private void checkPlayService() {
         int isGPSAvailable = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(MainActivity.this);

            Toast.makeText(this,"isGPSAvailable " + isGPSAvailable,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            switch (isGPSAvailable)
            {
                case ConnectionResult.API_UNAVAILABLE:
                    //API is not available
                    break;
                case ConnectionResult.NETWORK_ERROR:
                    //Network error while connection
                    break;
                case ConnectionResult.RESTRICTED_PROFILE:
                    //Profile is restricted by google so can not be used for play services
                    break;
                case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING:
                    //service is missing
                    break;
                case ConnectionResult.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED:
                    //service available but user not signed in
                    break;   case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_INVALID:
                    //  The version of the Google Play services installed on this device is not authentic
                    break;
                case ConnectionResult.SUCCESS:
                    break;
            }
}
```

Comment: Will the play store checking be enough for location and notification services control?

Comment: @elid if the issue you have related with availability of a service such as location or fcm in Play Services that should suffice. But if you need to access location via FusedLocationProvider api you should also check for location permission and gps settings either.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say :

> FCM clients require devices running Android 4.0 or higher that also
>   have the Google Play Store app installed, or an emulator running
>   Android 4.0 with Google APIs.

Furthermore:

> Apps that rely on the Play Services SDK should always check the device
>   for a compatible Google Play services APK before accessing Google Play
>   services features. It is recommended to do this in two places: in the
>   main activity's onCreate() method, and in its onResume() method. The
>   check in onCreate() ensures that the app can't be used without a
>   successful check. The check in onResume() ensures that if the user
>   returns to the running app through some other means, such as through
>   the back button, the check is still performed.

So yes you should always check for Google Play Services, though if you are distributing your application through Play Store it is safe to say that the Play Services would already be installed.

Comment: Very nice I will check in onCreate on OnResume? how about locations services ?